# How to customize Froala in angular 2?

Tags: angular, froala

I have added the Froala editor in my Angular 2 app and it works, I just cant find how to customize the toolbar, to show buttons that I want (bold, italic, underline, etc), any help?

https://github.com/froala/angular2-froala-wysiwyg

Comment: Maybe a look at the documentation will help? https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/customize

Comment: @ArrowHead I formulated the question wrong, I am interested in how to display only the buttons I want.. Edited the question

Comment: This should help https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/docs/options#toolbarButtons

Answer (score 4):

You can add option like this:

```
<div 
    *ngIf="homeIsInEditMode" 
    [froalaEditor]="options" 
    [(ngModel)]="homeMessage.libelleMessage"> 
</div>
```

And in component add options you want:

```
public options: Object = {
    placeholderText: 'Edit Your Content Here!',
    charCounterCount: false,
    toolbarButtons: ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'paragraphFormat','alert'],
    toolbarButtonsXS: ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'paragraphFormat','alert'],
    toolbarButtonsSM: ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'paragraphFormat','alert'],
    toolbarButtonsMD: ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'paragraphFormat','alert'],
}
```

You can get more details in the [official](https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/docs) documentation.

Answer (score 3):

add this

```
import 'froala-editor/js/plugins/font_size.min.js';
import 'froala-editor/js/plugins/font_family.min.js';
import 'froala-editor/js/plugins/emoticons.min.js';
import 'froala-editor/js/plugins/colors.min.js';
```

to a module where you want to insert editor

I think it is a very bad implementation, but it work

Answer (score 0):

You can find an example here of setting custom options in [the Angular Demo](https://github.com/froala/angular-froala-wysiwyg/blob/master/demo/src/app/app.component.ts#L115). The editor has 4 options for controlling the toolbar, as explained on https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/examples/toolbar-buttons:

> toolbarButtons for large devices (≥ 1200px)
>
> toolbarButtonsMD for medium devices (≥ 992px)
>
> toolbarButtonsSM for small devices (≥ 768px)
>
> toolbarButtonsXS for extra small devices (< 768px)